# Node.js file write in loop fails randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my code :

```
function aCallbackInLoop(dataArray) {
        dataArray.forEach(function (item, index) {

            fs.appendFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(item) + "\r\n", function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error writing data ' + err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Data written');
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

I get random errors :

```
Data written
Data written
.
.
Error writing data Error: UNKNOWN, open 'output/mydata.json'
Error writing data Error: UNKNOWN, open 'output/mydata.json'
.
.
Data written
Error writing data Error: UNKNOWN, open 'output/mydata.json'
```

The function (aCallbackInLoop) is a callback for a web-service request, which returns chunks of data in dataArray. Multiple web-service requests are being made in a loop, so this callback is perhaps being called in parallel. I doubt it's some file lock issue, but I am not sure how to resolve.

PS: I have made sure it's not a data issue (I am logging all items in dataArray)

Edit : Code after trying write stream :

```
function writeDataToFile(fileName, data) {
    try {
        var wStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
        wStream.write(JSON.stringify(data) + "\r\n");
        wStream.end();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}

function aCallbackInLoop(dataArray){
    dataArray.forEach(function(item, index){
        writeDataToFile(filename, item);   //filename is global var
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the synchronous version of `appendFile` - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_filename_data_options

Comment: This solves the issue, but I am still hoping to get the async way to work. If not, I will mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: Using a synchronous version is rarely the right way to go in a node.js server.

Comment: @jfriend00 - True, but with the given context of writing to the same file again and again, the sync is the best approach. OP might have to redesign.

Comment: @manojlds - no it is NOT the best approach.  Using synchronous I/O anywhere in a node.js server (other than startup code) absolutely kills the scalability because the single threaded nature of node.js means no other request can be processed while the server is sitting there waiting for disk I/O to complete.  There are plenty of other options that don't ruin the scalability.  A write stream, nested async writes, chained promise writes are all much better options.

Answer (score 8):

As you have observed, multiple `appendFile` calls are not able to proceed because of the previous `appendFile` calls. In this particular case, it would be better to create a [write stream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options).

```
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);

dataArray.forEach(function (item) {
    wstream.write(JSON.stringify(item + "\r\n");
});

wstream.end();
```

If you want to know when all the data is written, then you can register a function with the [`finish`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) event, like this

```
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);

wstream.on("finish", function() {
    // Writing to the file is actually complete.
});

dataArray.forEach(function (item) {
    wstream.write(JSON.stringify(item + "\r\n");
});

wstream.end();
```

Comment: I see this is the right way to go, but I am still getting the error. If I use appendFileSync - then everything works. But I don't want to use the synchronous version. Still wondering what am I doing wrong !

Comment: @SlowAndSteady Can you show the actual code which you tried?

Comment: @SlowAndSteady Why are you creating a stream for every data? Better change it like the way I have shown (create stream only once) and try.

Comment: Actually the writeDataToFile is in a seperate module/file and it's a utility to handle multiple functionalities depending on the fileName I pass. I am trying to avoid the clients of this utility to open any file streams etc. Why would multiple streams be an issue though ? Shouldn't the streams just wait in case someone else has lock on the resource ?

Comment: It seems I would have to reengineer my design. Will try and update !

Comment: @SlowAndSteady Node.js is not multithreaded, so there is no locking as such. When you create multiple write streams to write to the same file, the data will be overwritten.